# Irregular shaped view in react-native?

Tags: react-native, view

How can I design a following view. I tried with borderWidth adjustment and transprency. Help me.
How can the following '30% off' view can be made ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
<View style={{
  width: 62,
  height: 0,
  borderBottomColor: colors.yellow,
  borderBottomWidth: 15,
  borderLeftWidth: 15,
  borderRightWidth: 15,
  borderRightColor: 'transparent',
  borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
  transform: [{ rotate: '315deg' }],
  top: 9,
  left: -15,
  position: 'absolute',
}}
>
    <Text style={{fontFamily: 'Montserrat_Medium', fontSize: 9, color: colors.white, marginTop: 1}}>25% off</Text>
</View>
```